# How to select specific time range in AWS Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

In Grafana, I use AWS Timestream as data source. And I want to show only specific time range such as 9:00 to 21:00. AWS Timestream supports SQL so I write like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM testDB.testTable
WHERE measure_name = 'test'
AND time BETWEEN time('09:00:00') AND time('21:00:00')
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10080
```

But I got the following error. Could you tell me what is wrong with it?

> ValidationException: line 4:18: Problems with function : time. Either
> the function does not exist, or there is a problem with a dependent
> function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM testDB.testTable
WHERE measure_name = 'test'
AND hour(time) BETWEEN 9 AND 20
ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 10080
```

The above query will fetch records which hours are between '*09:00:00.000000000*' and '*20:59:59.999999999*'